# How to duplicate rows in google sheets based on an app script prompt

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I am trying to write a script to duplicate the last row. The number of times the row will be duplicated will be based on the input from the user when prompted. I get the window that creates the prompt, but after that, the rows are not duplicated. Could you please help

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Duplicate Rows', 'showDialog')
    .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Duplicate Rows', 'How many rows would you like to duplicate?',        ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    const numRows = parseInt(response.getResponseText());
    if (isNaN(numRows) || numRows < 1) {
      ui.alert('Invalid input. Please enter a valid number greater than 0.');
      return;
    }
    duplicateRows(numRows);
  }
}

function duplicateRows(numRows) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    const destinationRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow + i + 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    destinationRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

About `I get the window that creates the prompt, but after that, the rows are not duplicated.`, when I tested your script, for example, when 5 is inputted to the prompt and click "ok" button, 5 rows are copied under the last row. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. But, in your script, a row is copied in the loop. I'm worried whether this might be related to your current issue. But, this is just my guess. So, can you test the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `duplicateRows` is modified.

```js
function duplicateRows(numRows) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  const dstValues = Array(numRows).fill(sourceValues[0]);
  sourceRange.offset(1, 0, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- By this modification, the last row is copied by one call of `setValue`.

#### References:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)